# sendAsynchronousRequest is not getting called after dispatch_group_enter

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I want to wait for several async tasks to finish and try to achieve it with dispatch_group, see Apple docs: [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html).

However when I enter the dispatch group the `sendAsynchronousRequest` just doesn't return a response. The log doesn't show any error. What am I doing wrong?

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_enter(group);
// get Data from Server
NSString *url = [ConfigurationManager getDomain];
url = [url stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:URL_GET_JACKPOT]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setTimeoutInterval:TIMEOUT_INTERVAL];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

// not getting response
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *responseCode, NSData *responseData, NSError *error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)responseCode;
    if([httpResponse statusCode] != 200){
        NSLog(@"@Error: Error getting %@, HTTP status code %li, Error: %@", url, (long)[httpResponse statusCode], error);
        
    }else{
        // process result
        
    }
    dispatch_group_leave(group); // this never gets called -> deadlock
}];
dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the response of `sendAsynchronousRequest` gets executed on the main thread, **which I am not on** (cause of dispatch_enter). When I create my own `NSOperationQueue` object it works.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *responseCode, NSData *responseData, NSError *error) {
  // etc..
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you said, try to use different queues else you will get the deadlock.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    // get Data from Server
    NSString *url = [ConfigurationManager getDomain];
    url = [url stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:URL_GET_JACKPOT]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:TIMEOUT_INTERVAL];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    // not getting response
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *responseCode, NSData *responseData, NSError *error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)responseCode;
        if([httpResponse statusCode] != 200){
            NSLog(@"@Error: Error getting %@, HTTP status code %li, Error: %@", url, (long)[httpResponse statusCode], error);

        }else{
            // process result

        }
        dispatch_group_leave(group); // this never gets called -> deadlock
    }];
    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
});
```